# Finding the width of a bell-shaped curve at half its peak value dynamically in a Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, peak-detection

Kind of new to *Mathematica*. I am plotting a function that produces a bell-shaped curve in *Mathematica* within a `Manipulate` so that I can change its parameters easily. When I change the parameters of the function with the controls, I want the width of the bell-shaped curve at half its peak value recalculated.

How do I add this additional feature?

Comment: What kind of function are you plotting?

Comment: the function is very complicated but basically it is an exponential multiplied to a BesselK. the plot looks like a normal distribution though

Comment: Then, you can use `NMaximize[]` and `FindRoot[]` to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just post this as a motivating toy example. There are many ways to do this and this approach may not suit.

```
fun[x_, p_] := Exp[-x^2/(2 p)]
tfun[step_, b_, p_] := Table[{j, fun[j, p]}, {j, -b, b, step}]
parf[s_, b_, p_] := Module[{data = tfun[s, b, p], pk, n, c},
  pk = FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]]][[1, 2]];
  n = Nearest[data[[All, 2]], pk/2, 2];
  c = Join @@ (Cases[data, {_, #}, All] & /@ n);
  ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
   Epilog -> {Line[c], 
     Text[Framed@Abs[c[[2, 1]] - c[[1, 1]]], {0, pk/2}, {0, -1}, 
      Background -> White]}]]
```

Visualizing:

```
  Manipulate[parf[0.001, b, p], {b, 2, 4}, {p, 0.5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: @PhilCsar I think Jason B's answer is more general than mine. Thank you for the vote but look at his answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

This function will find the full-width at half-maximum for an arbitrary function within a given range, provided that there is only one peak in that range:

```
fwhm[func_Function, {min_, max_}] := Module[{val, maxx, x},
  {val, maxx} = {#1, x /. #2} & @@ 
    NMaximize[{func[x], x > min, x < max}, x];
  Chop@{maxx, 
    Abs[#1 - #2] & @@ (x /. 
       NSolve[{func[x] == val/2, x > min, x < max}, x])}]
```

The returned values are the peak position, and the FWHM value.

```
fwhm[Sin[#]/(#) &, {-10, 10}]
fwhm[Function[y, Exp[-y^2/2]], {-10, 10}]
fwhm[Re[I/(# - 2. + 3. I)] &, {-10, 10}]
fwhm[Function[y, Sin[π y]], {4, 5}]
fwhm[Function[y, 1 - y^2/3^2], {-10, 10}]
(* {-2.21056*10^-9, 3.79099} *)
(* {0, 2.35482} *)
(* {2., 6.} *)
(* {4.5, 0.666667} *)
(* {0, 4.24264} *)
```

These values match what you find at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FullWidthatHalfMaximum.html) (can you spot the typo there?)

You can integrate this into a `Manipulate` call, it's a reasonably fast function.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{peak, width},
  {peak, width} = fwhm[Exp[-#^2/(2 a)] &, {-20, 20}];
  Show[
   Plot[Exp[-x^2/(2 a)], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    Frame -> True, Axes -> False],
   Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Arrow[{
       {peak - .5 width, Exp[-(peak - .5 width)^2/(2 a)]},
       {peak + .5 width, Exp[-(peak + .5 width)^2/(2 a)]}}
      ]}],
   Epilog -> Inset[Row[{"FWHM = ", width}], {7, .8}]
   ]
  ]
 , {{a, 1}, .5, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: really like your answer +1 :)

Comment: @ubpdqn thank you!  I couldn't decide whether `FindRoot` or `NSolve` was a better way to go, but it was easy enough to get `NSolve` to return both values so I went with it.  Sometimes it will spit back an error about exact/inexact values, but it still gave an answer so I slapped `Quiet` on there.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for the width at half height as a function of $\sigma$, then just list it:

```
Manipulate[{
  Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, σ], x], {x, -3, 3},
   PlotRange -> All], 
  N@Sqrt[2] σ Sqrt[Log[2]]},
  {σ, .1, 3}]
```

Comment: This solution is specialized for Gaussians, tho.