# Why am I getting errors from NMaximize?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I tried to use the function that is given in [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108624/finding-the-width-of-a-bell-shaped-curve-at-half-its-peak-value-dynamically-in-a) in order to get the FWHM of some expression I got from solving a system of linear equations.

This is the function for calculating FWHM:

```
fwhm[func_Function, {min_, max_}] := 
  Module[{val, maxx, x}, 
    {val, maxx} = {#1, x /. #2} & @@ NMaximize[{func[x], x > min, x < max}, x];
    Chop @ 
      {maxx, Abs[#1 - #2] & @@ (x /. NSolve[{func[x] == val/2, x > min, x < max}, x])}]
```

I put my expression `F` as a function inside `fwhm`:

```
fwhm[Function[x, -F], {-0.01, 0.01}]
```

and I got many errors from `NMaximize`, all of them were like this:

> NMaximize::nnum: The function value ......(here comse the expression F)...... is not a number at {x$53711} = {-0.00868794}.

Does someone here know what it means, and how to solve the problem?

F is:

[image]

Comment: `Function[x, -F]` is probably incorrectly constructed. What is the definition of `F`? Without that, we may not be able to help.

Comment: Maybe `Function[x, Evaluate[-F]]` helps...

Comment: Yes! The Evaluate helps! Thank you Henrik.

Answer (score 1):

Define

```
F[x_] = (6.36968*^-8 Sqrt[x^2 + 0.0144] (1. Sqrt[x^2 + 2.13891*^-6] - 1. Sqrt[x^2 + 2.44141*^-6]))/Sqrt[x^6 + 0.00357394 x^4 + 1.15295*^-8 x^2 + 7.48288*^-15]
```

then this works fine:

```
fwhm[Function[x, -F[x]], {-0.01, 0.01}]
```

> {0, 0.00192788}